# C++ : Fastest Way to find number of elements of one array in another array

Tags: c++, arrays, search

I have two arrays, one sorted array `int b[]` and other unsorted array `int a[n] having n elements` . The sorted array is made of some or all elements of unsorted array. Now there are M queries. For each query values of *l* and *r*  are given. In each query I need to find the number of elements of `a[n]` which are present in `b[]`.

For eg -

```
N=5 ,M=2
a= [2 5 1 2 3]
b=[3 2 1]
for each m:
l=1 r=5 ->a[1]=1, a[5]=5 -> answer should be 3 as all elements of b i.e 1,2,3 are present in a
l=2 r=4 ->a[2]=5 , a[4]=2 ->answer should be 2 as only 1 and 2 are there in b for given value of l and r for array.
```

How to find the answer with not more than *O(M* *  *LOGN)* time complexity ?

**NOTE:**
Array is not necessary. Vector can also be used that is if it helps in reducing time complexity or easier to implement the code.

Comment: This sounds a lot like _homework_. Right? Unfortunately, SO is not a code writing service. What did you try until now? What's the actual problem you are facing with your code?

Comment: @skypjack Sorry but It's not a homework. It's a part of question solved using DP. Now to compute the final answer I need to compute as asked in the question. Well I tried using nested for loop, but the time limit exceeds.

Comment: Can't come up with much from top of the head.. but.. are elements of array unique? you could pop found array members, avoiding to iterate them later,  and inner loop should be on sorted array to exploit branch prediction?

Comment: @Swift Elements in unsorted array are not necessarily unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i think you can do something like this

```
std::map<int,int> c;
for(int i = 0;i<b.length.i++){
   c[b[i]] = 0;
}
for(int i = l; i<=r; i++){
   int number = a[i];
   c[number]++;
}
//Iterate through c with b index and get all number which different than 0. The left is for you
```

The purpose of this is creating a map hold index of B. Then while iterating A you can increase the c value. So that after that you can check whether each element in C has value different than zero mean that A has hold the number of B.
You can use array instead of map if C starting from zero and increase by 1 for better performance. Make sure to check if a[i]  can throw out of bounds exception if you use array.

Comment: Can you please include the loop for answer ? And For *M* queries, this would give a time complexity of **O(M N)**. I need to reduce this time complexity.

Comment: If you really want that fast. Just create a matrix[x][y] with x equal left and y equal right. Parse all result into the matrix and then you can have a O(1) for M queries just by return matrix[l][r].